# how to add a view in place of keyboard when we click accessory button using jsq message view controller

Tags: swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

how to add a UIView in place of keyboard when we click accessory button using JSQ message view controller in swift 
i am using JSQ message library in my app so i want add a UIView in which there are stack view which i want to show on on the click of accessary button in swift.
I created the View on storyboard, on click of accessory button this view will show.
[image]
I don't understand where this view will append in chat screen.

```
    override func didPressAccessoryButton(sender: UIButton!){ 
self.inputToolbar.contentView.addView(View)
}
```

that will produce the nil exception

That my view i want to appent on the keyboard when accessary button click

Comment: I am not familiar with swift much.
But yeah first thing you have to do is resign textview responder     [self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView resignFirstResponder];

And then add your view.
It will be better if you provide with a dummy image what you exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just adding your "Custom View" to the main view and giving it constraints to be where the keyboard is normally not actually adding it to the keyboard view.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to have such effect and add your desired subview instead of demoView:

[image]

```
  [self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView resignFirstResponder];
  UIView *demoView = [UIView new];
  demoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

In below line you can decide the frame you want:

```
  demoView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.inputToolbar.contentView.width/2, self.inputToolbar.contentView.height);
  [self.inputToolbar.contentView addSubview:demoView];
```

And if you want some other kind of view like below:

[image]

```
  [self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView resignFirstResponder];
  UIView *demoView = [UIView new];
  demoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  demoView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.width, 200);
  [self.view addSubview:demoView];
```

Comment: i want to show in place of keyboard when click left button it like a toggle button and input toolbar remain the at the same place